# Does Ruby on Rails' ActiveRecord support "disconnected recordsets" (like ADO.net)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, ado.net, activerecord, database-connection

Using Microsoft's ADO.net, one can you query database -> disconnect database connection -> query/manipulate locally -> connect again (re-synchronize local with database).

I've found value in this as overall it can minimize database hits.

Does ActiveRecord support such a model/pattern?

Comment: I guess the answer is "ActiveRecord" doesn't support disconnected operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimizing database hits can be handled without closing database connections.

Database connections are expensive resources, opening and closing them will slow your app down.